# Setting up the datetime picker

Tags: jquery

I'm really new to web development, in my web i need to have datetime picker and im trying to use [trentrichardson](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)'s datetime picker, Unfortunately i was unable to make it work.
this is my javascript

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

can any one help me, how to set up this datetime picker..

Comment: `unable to make it work` means what? Provide more details, html code, how you have written the head tag etc

Comment: Do you have an element on your page with the ID `datepicker`? Have you loaded jQuery and the plugin correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With very less information from OP, I will give a try.

Your code should look like this (considering you have a folder `js` in your root folder, with all the javascripts.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- Add your CSS file here -->

     <!-- Add your Java Script files here -->       
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
         $( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker();
     });
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
  </body>
</html>
```

For javascript to work, all the components required by the javascript function should be pre-loaded on client browser.

Inside `head` tag the **suggested order** is

1. **CSS**: Include CSS first, so that browser gets it first, and render website correctly.
2. **JavaScripts**: Once it is render properly, javascripts should be loaded so that user can interact with the website.
3. **Inline Javascript** : (if any, considering you are using some components from the pre-loaded libraries.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for you detailed answer, 
I copied all JavaScript to a jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js file and included in to my js folder,and I also have jquery-1.7.1.min.js,jquery-1.7.1.min.js in that folder, but still im getting some errors ,
Saying $datepicker is undefined , $timepicker is undefined ,
Do you know the reason ?

Comment: Does `datepicker` & `timepicker` controls exists on your html? check the ID? They need to be of type `input`, check my answer for more information.

Comment: No I don't have those in my html,my html contains only your above code. firefox error console says those two are not defined in jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Comment: Now its working ,there was a little mistake with one of names the files, Thank you very much ,

Answer (score 2):

firstly you will need to download the javascript file and the css stylesheet file for calendar.

to download you this link 
       http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Once you have downloaded the file create a html file and refer to the style and javascript to this downloaded files also remember you add jQuery Library file in your HTML.

Create the HTML as per the need and use the script in you DOM ready.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker();
});
```

note: `#datepicker` id the ID of the html element where you need the calendar to pop up .

You can also read the readme provided with the download.

> ## jQuery Timepicker Addon
>
> ### Use
>
> - To use this plugin you must include jQuery and jQuery UI with datepicker and slider
> - Include timepicker-addon script
> - now use timepicker with $('#selector').datetimepicker() or $('#selector').timepicker()
>
> Contributing Code - Please Read!
>   -------------------------------- All code contributions and bug reports are much appreciated.  Please be sure to apply your fixes to
>   the "dev" branch.

copied from the readme file which was downloaded along with the files.

Answer (score 2):

Try to load jquery library file and the datetimepicker plugin.
Debug Tips:

> Press **ctrl + shift + j** (Firefox) for error console

it will display the jquery or javascript errors

Answer (score 1):

Did you load jQuery? 
think its even better to put this functionality on the page after it's loaded by:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: For this plugin you require:
- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- jQuery datetime picker plugin
All of the above need to be loaded

Comment: The `$(function() {...});` syntax is just a shorter version of `$(document).ready(function() {...});`.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't familiar with that

Answer (score 0):

with HTML5 this is as simple as:-

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="bdaytime">
```

edit:-
I have found that this might be at risk of being removed so do some googling if you are using it in the future just to mmake sure it does not get deprecated.